# Photoelectric effect high frequency limit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

The photoelectric effect has a low frequency limit below which nothing is observed.

Increasing the frequency energy is enough to free an electron. Continuing to increase the frequency the material will start to be more transparent and interact weakly with radiation.

My question is in what range is the Einstein photoelectric effect true.

Comment: The photoelectric effect requires photons with energies from a few electronvolts to over 1 MeV in high atomic number elements. It really depends on the material you're talking about. Different materials have different work functions (energy required to free an electron in very loose terms), and an electron in the material requires that much energy from the incident frequency to get liberated.

Comment: The lower limit, as Hasan points out, is limited by the material in question. The upper limit would probably be dependent on the source of photons.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you call photo effect is the photoelectric effect. It's range is from a few $\mathrm{eV}$ to the $\mathrm{MeV}$ scale (for highly massive particles). The other possible effects are: the Compton effect ($50 \,\mathrm{KeV}$ to $3 \,\mathrm{MeV}$) and pair production (over $1 \,\mathrm{MeV}$).

Comment: I have an edit in the queue that changes the `photoeffect` to `photoelectric effect`. That was an hour ago.

Comment: I guess the work function will also change increasing the energy. Might be wrong but at high energy only the core electrons will have high enough cross section to interact with the photons. The question is if the binding energy of the most tightly bound electron is 1000eV let say, would a photon do anything to the material if it has significantly higher energy and do not interact anymore?

Comment: Note that in the few MeV energy range photon-nucleus interactions start to become significant as well.